# HTML5 Cache Manifest works over http but not https

Tags: django, html, https, manifest

My google-fu does not seem up to snuff today so here it goes...

I have a django application sitting on top of apache using wsgi. I am attempting to make this work offline. I serve the Cache Manifest file from a django url with the correct mimetype and a no-cache header. I have a manifest reference in the template that looks like

```
<html lang="en" manifest="/myPath/manifest/">
```

In order to debug this problem I am using the simplest of manifest files first

CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:

*

However, this gives me the  following errors in chrome when I attempt to serve it via the https interface.

> Creating Application Cache with
>   manifest
>   https://127.0.0.1/myPath/manifest/
>   Application Cache Checking event
>   Application Cache Error event:
>   Manifest fetch failed (-1)
>   https://127.0.0.1/myPath/manifest/

When served over http it appears to work correctly. I am using a self signed security certificate on my development machine. This is the only thing that I can think might make the difference between http and https serving the same manifest file(using relative links so the origin is correct). What is causing the difference between http and https, and how to I correct it?

Comment: Not sure if there's anything here that might help you: http://diveintohtml5.org/offline.html

Comment: You're sure that under HTTPS you're really getting the same file with the same headers? (I would assume so since it's being served from Django and not apache, but still.)

Answer (score 7):

I'd blame your self-signed certificate.

Chrome and Firefox, if the scary-looking warning dialogs weren't enough, are quite anal about self-signed certificates. For example, [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) does not work with self-signed certificates in either browser.

Comment: I had this problem on one of my fake environments with self-signed certs.  Works fine w/ a real cert.

Comment: I have been banging my head on the wall for quite some time with this one, it's a pitty that i found the answer(s) only after i figured it out by trial and error. It seems google has some work to do with documenting this issue.